# Inconsistent results using EE Simple Search with Solspace Calendar

Tags: search, simple-search

I am using EE's Simple Search [here](http://mobilearts.org/calendar/) to search the Solspace default channel Calendar:Events.

Here is the code

```
<div class="calendar-search">
    <h3>Search Events</h3>
    {exp:search:simple_form 
        channel="calendar_events" 
        search_in="everywhere" 
        where="any"
        show_future_entries="yes" 
        show_expired="yes"
        results="10" 
        result_page="calendar/search-results" 
        no_result_page="search/no-results"
        }
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="search-btn">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
</div>
```

For most search items this works fine and delivers predictable results. However, there are a couple of things that don't work and I haven't been able to find solutions to the following:

1. No results for items I know are in the entries. For example, there is an event with the title of **Lego Club**, but if I do a search for **Lego**, I get a blank results page.
2. The No Results page is not being used for items that are not in the channel. For example, if I do a search for **Nikon**, instead of going to the designated no_result_page it goes to a default EE page that displays the following error:

> The action you have requested is invalid.

I am not sure why these errors are occurring or how to fix them, but would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your #2 is related to EE's "Secure Mode" with form submissions. You can read more about it here:
https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/putting-the-secure-in-secure-mode-forms

Try adding this line of code immediately above your "keywords" input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">
```

This may also fix your #1 issue but I can't say for sure. I'd imagine that without the {XID_HASH} code in place, none of your searches would work but since lots are working I'm a little perplexed. Give this a try.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I applied the line of code you recommended and I am still getting the same funny results: blank results page and no redirect to the no-results page. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try disabling "Secure Forms" in your configure file temporarily. I think the code is: config['secure_forms'] = "n";

Comment: @fmz if adding that code fixes your issue it means it is related to secure forms and you'll need to try tracking things backwards.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't make any difference. I appreciate your efforts, but I am going to have to keep looking.